\Undefined Control Sequence error when I try to color a table
I use Miktex + TexMaker in daily production, in my daily work, sometimes I need to color some elements of the table, but it always fails when I try to use the package xcolor or colortbl.
Therefore, I created a simple example to test:

Just load the xcolor to color a text, success.
Use xcolor to color a tabular, fails, no output:
Script:

\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}  

\begin{document}   
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}   
\hline   
\rowcolor{yellow} Header 1 & Header 2 \\   
\hline   
\cellcolor{lightgray} Row 1 & Data \\   
\hline 
Row 2 & Data 2 \\   
\hline   
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}

Log:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.11.7)  7 NOV 2024 13:24 entering
extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
**./tst2.tex (tst2.tex LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2 L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03> (C:\Program
Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls Document Class: article
2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class (C:\Program
Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo File: size10.clo
2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count175
\c@section=\count176 \c@subsection=\count177
\c@subsubsection=\count178 \c@paragraph=\count179
\c@subparagraph=\count180 \c@figure=\count181 \c@table=\count182
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47 \belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138 ) (C:\Program
Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty Package: xcolor
2024/09/29 v3.02 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor-2022-06-12.sty
Package: xcolor-2022-06-12 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions
(UK)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg File:
color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration ) Package xcolor
Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex )
(C:\Users\bokbb\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/colortbl\colortbl.sty
Package: colortbl 2024/07/06 v1.0i Color table columns (DPC)

(C:\Users\bokbb\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2024/06/01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2020-10-01' is available.

Package: array 2024/06/14 v2.6d Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen139 \ar@mcellbox=\box47 \extrarowheight=\dimen140
\NC@list=\toks15 \extratabsurround=\skip49 \backup@length=\skip50
\ar@cellbox=\box48 ) \everycr=\toks16 \minrowclearance=\skip51
\rownum=\count183 ) (C:\Program
Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \mathcolor with sig. 'omm' on line 29.

) Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line
1353. Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357. Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line
1369. Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371. Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on
input line 1372. Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by
`hsb' on input line 1373. Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted
by `hsb' on input line 1374. Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray'
substituted by `gray' on input line 1375. Package xcolor Info: Model
`wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376. )) (C:\Program
Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def File:
l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output
(pdfTeX) \l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count184
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box49 ) (tst2.aux) \openout1 = `tst2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
4. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4. LaTeX Font Info:  
... okay on input line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input
line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4. LaTeX Font Info:
Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4. LaTeX Font Info:   
... okay on input line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input
line 4. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.  (C:\Program
Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii [Loading MPS
to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] \scratchcounter=\count185
\scratchdimen=\dimen141 \scratchbox=\box50 \nofMPsegments=\count186
\nofMParguments=\count187 \everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count188 \MPscratchDim=\dimen142 \MPnumerator=\count189
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count190 \everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18 ) !
Undefined control sequence. \@tabular ->\leavevmode \UseTaggingSocket 
                                          {tbl/hmode/begin}\hbox \bgroup $\c... l.6 \begin{tabular}
                   {|c|c|} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size (Font)     
<7> on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded
for size (Font)              <5> on input line 6. ! Undefined control
sequence. \@@array ...idth \z@ }\tbl_save_outer_table_cols: 
                                                  \begingroup \@mkpream {#2}... l.6 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                           The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.

! Undefined control sequence. \insert@column ->\UseTaggingSocket 
                                   {tbl/cell/begin}\the@toks \the \@tempcnta... l.6 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                           The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.

! Undefined control sequence. \insert@column ...count@ \relax
\UseTaggingSocket 
                                                  {tbl/cell/end} l.6 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                           The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.

! Undefined control sequence. \@preamble ...yrulewidth
}&\tbl_update_cell_data: 
                                                   l.6 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                           The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.

! Undefined control sequence. \insert@column ->\UseTaggingSocket 
                                   {tbl/cell/begin}\the@toks \the \@tempcnta... l.6 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                           The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.

! Undefined control sequence. \insert@column ...count@ \relax
\UseTaggingSocket 
                                                  {tbl/cell/end} l.6 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                           The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.

! Undefined control sequence. \@@array ... \@mkpream
{#2}\tbl_count_table_cols: 
                                                  \xdef \@preamble {\noexpan... l.6 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                           The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
undefined.

! Undefined control sequence. \@@arra


Just load colortbl, fails.

Use colortbl to color a tabular, fails, no output.

Directly create a tabular, success


I have tried uninstall and install Miktex twice, no effect. Also I have tried in TeXWorks, got same feedback
Can anyone help me with my issue? Thank you in advance.

Please add your code as text in a code block and not as an image

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please try to make your question clear and simple by providing a minimal working example.

Do not show error messages as a screenshot of an editor summary, show the actual errro from the log. But it looks like you are using a very new xcolor on an old latex release. How did you install xcolor ?

Hi David, I install it inside MiKTeX Console, by searching it inside 'Packages' menu

There seems to be a mix of old and new package versions on your system.

Thank you all, I tried update in my console sever times, then it works.
But it shows this error: This application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized miktex.
Attach the link of solution:
https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1486

Likely a problem of not updating MiKTeX as Admin.

your log shows you have a 2024 xcolor and a 2020 latex format which should never happen update miktex in user and admin mode

Note you have a mixture of two installations one under C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\MiKTeX and one under C:\Users\bokbb\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX I don't use miktex but that is a sign of inconsistent updates, always update both admin and user mode
